# Apache autoindex showing empty file list

Tags: apache-2.4, permissions, indexing

I'm trying to enable directory listing for a folder outside the web root that uses Basic Authentication, but I'm getting an empty list and no logged errors. What's strange is that if I put in the known location of a file under this directory in my browser, it downloads the file just fine. This tells me it's not a read permissions issue.

Here's my `example.conf` file:

```
<virtualhost *:80>

  ServerAdmin donotreply@blah.com
  ServerName  example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com


  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/apachelogs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/apachelogs/access.log combined

  Alias /blah2 "/blah1/blah2"
    <Location /blah2>
              Options +Indexes +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
              IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
    </Location>


</virtualhost>
```

And here's my `.htaccess`

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
AuthUserFile "/home/myusername/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

Also, I've commented `IndexIgnore` out in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/autoindex.conf`

```
#IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# RCS CVS *,v *,t
```

Comment: btw authentication is working just fine.

Comment: increase LogLevel to debug or trace4 and try using Require valid-user in the location tag. I used inline AuthType in httpd.conf under Location and worked fine.

Comment: thanks for the advice. moving auth didn't resolve the issue. also, removing auth completely and replacing it with `Require all granted` doesn't resolve the issue.  Here's my trace4 https://pastebin.com/nXz2rzb9

Comment: looks like w3cache was adding a bunch of noise to that log, so I renamed my root .htaccess and reran the log.  much simpler now. https://pastebin.com/uB2kctQi

Comment: I've just determined that this is a permissions issue. Made a directory in /home/username/, gave it 750 permissions and then pointed my alias there.  Worked as expected.

Comment: I'm going to move this question to askubuntu, since it seems to be related to permissions.